# Msg 2812 : "Create Table Using Dynamic Script"

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, dynamic-tables

I wanted to create a table using dynamic SQL.

If I creates a table using

```
CREATE Table TodayTemp(id varchar(20))
DROP TABLE TodayTemp
```

Then there is no problem. It works fine. But problem using this is I can't create columns dynamically. Hence I tried using store create script in a variable and then finally execute them using `EXEC` command.

Like

```
Declare @CreateTableCmd varchar(max)
SET @CreateTableCmd = 'CREATE Table TodayTemp(id varchar(20))'
Exec @CreateTableCmd
```

But this causes an error

> Msg 2812, Level 16, State 62, Line 6
>   Could not find stored procedure 'CREATE Table TodayTemp(id varchar(20))'.

Comment: BTW your fiddle shows nothing.

Comment: Actually Fiddel don't changes its URL till any thing done without any error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add parentheses around your variable when executing

```
Declare @CreateTableCmd varchar(max)
SET @CreateTableCmd = 'CREATE Table TodayTemp (id varchar(20))'
Exec (@CreateTableCmd)
     ^---------------^--------here
```

### [SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/fa387)

Comment: Excellent answer. There's some additional info here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa175921%28v=sql.80%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

if you want to exec your script with exec, call it like this:

```
Exec (@CreateTableCmd)
```

Another way to do this is to use [sp_executesql](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx) stored procedure:

```
exec sp_executesql @stmt = @CreateTableCmd
```

there're many links comparing this two approaches:

- https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/4559/difference-between-exec-and-sp-executesql-with-no-parameters
- http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/kimberly/exec-and-sp_executesql-how-are-they-different/

Answer (score 0):

```
Declare @CreateTableCmd varchar(max)
SET @CreateTableCmd = 'CREATE Table TodayTemp'
Exec (@CreateTableCmd)
```

That should do the trick

Raj